# Oblique collisions in classical gas

Tags: simulations, ideal-gas

I am trying to simulate the collisions in classical gas. So the particles are point like and have identical mass. It is easy to find who collides with whom but the what happens to the particles after they collide is bit tricky.

Since if the collision were to be only head-on the energy distribution of particles will not change, only their momentum and energy will get exchanged.

Certainly I need to include the oblique collisions in order to change the distribution. So my question is how to accomplish the oblique collisions for the point particles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to recognize that they are not really point particles. Once you treat them as (small) spheres, you can compute the momentum exchange as a function of lateral offset between them. Some details of the calculation are given in [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/222481/26969)

The math is the same regardless of the size of the spheres - that is, the ratio of probabilities of an almost-head-on vs a slightly-oblique vs a very-oblique collision will be the same; this means that once you normalize to the "total probability of a collision", the actual size of the particles becomes irrelevant.

Comment: So the basically when we (or more accurately wikipedia) say, "An ideal gas is a theoretical gas composed of many randomly moving point particles that do not interact except when they collide elastically." is wrong? or is it okay in limiting cases? I think a limiting case is more correct than saying point particles since without finite-tiny spheres we can not get the ideal gas.

Comment: But the point-particles can also collide at some angle i.e. point particles, moving along the intersecting straight lines, can also collide at some angle instead of colliding in opposite direction or head on. That means not only spheres but also point-particles can make oblique collision (at some angle)

Comment: Yes it's the limiting case. We consider a gas ideal when the volume occupied by the molecules is much less than the volume of the container - then the ideal gas law holds. The moment the molecules have a finite size, the pressure will increase more rapidly than $1/V$ because the distance traveled from one wall of the container to the other is $d-2r$ where $d$ is the distance between the walls, and $r$ is the radius.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot - how do you compute an oblique angle when you have true point particles? The have no size, so they can either hit head-on (when their velocity vectors are colinear) or they miss (for any offset in velocity).  You have to consider the limiting case of a sphere in order to get around that...

Comment: @Floris: I am not saying true point-particle, The particles having negligible size $\to 0$ just as gas molecules. Do all gas molecules collide head-on??

Comment: You are agreeing with me then. You have to realize they are not _really_ points, but that their size is very very small. And that it doesn't matter, for the purpose of the momentum transfer calculation, exactly how small they are.

Answer (score 0):

In the center of mass frame of the colliding particles, rotate one particle's velocity vector's x-component by x degrees, y-component by y degrees, z-component by z degrees.

Then rotate other particle's velocity vector's x-component by -x degrees, y-component by -y degrees, z-component by -z degrees.

x,y,z are random numbers.

(Physical interpretation of that: the particles fused, then the fusion product fissioned, two identical parts flying into opposite directions)