# What happens when two balls collide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What happens when ball traveling at constant speed hit resting ball with

1. same mass
2. more mass
3. less mass

(ie. how diagram of balls speeds looks like)

Balls are made of same material and they collide in vacuum, there are no external forces (gravity etc.), moving ball hits resting ball head on.

Case 1 collisions are elastic.

Case 2 collisions are inelastic.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: There's not quite enough information to give a full answer.

Comment: @Farcher No. Just wondering.

Comment: @garyp What kind of information should I add?

Comment: Is the collision elastic (bounce without losing kinetic energy) or completely inelastic (stick together) or something in between?

Comment: Collision head on or at an angle?  Are the collisions elastic (no loss of kinetic energy or inelastic (loss of kinetic energy after collision)?

Comment: Very similar question was [answered here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/222481/26969)

Comment: This is just solving the usual equations for collisions. What about that can you not do yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elastic Collision Velocity of $Ball_1$ is Given by $v_1=u_1\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{2u_2m_2}{(m_1+m_2)} $

$Ball_2$ $V_2=\frac{2m_1u_1}{(m_1+m_2)}+\frac{u_2(m_2-m_1)}{m_1+m_2}$
Where u is initial Velocity(Velocity before Collision)

In Inelastic Collision Kinetic Energy after Impact is Less than kinetic energy before impact. The Loss in Kinetic Energy converted into Heat Energy

Comment: It looks like units don't add up in first equation.

Comment: This is Correct $v_1=u_1\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{2u_2m_2}{(m_1+m_2)}$

Comment: if  $m_1=m_2$ then $v_1=u_2$

Comment: if $m_1=m_2$ $v_2=u_1$

Comment: This assumes a 1-dimensional collision.  If you allow two dimensions, many more things can happen.  The OP did not specify.

Answer (score 0):

> As per your question `events 2 & 3` (i.e. more mass and less mass are relatively the same events).
>   Here I am considering that the events occur in *one dimension*.

**`Event 1`**:
When two bodies of equal mass collide elastically, their velocities get mutually interchanged.

**`Events 2 & 3`** are **`same`**:
When a very lighter mass collides with heavy mass elastically, the heavier body continues to move with almost the same speed.

The above conclusions should be intuitively clear although.
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) on elastic collisions.

Comment: It's interesting that energy is always transferred from the higer energy ball to the lower energy ball.  If that were not the case, our world would be quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

In the limiting case when there is no dissipation (loss of energy), this is called an elastic collision, and answers are well known (see other answers).

In the real world, this is never exactly the case, and depending on how much energy is dissipated (in the vacuum, by deformation of the bodies) you will have a result more or less close to this ideal limit. In the more complex cases, calculating the dynamics of deformation of each body (by numerical approximation in general) is necessary to have a definite answer.